# UserFrosting & AWS SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, userfrosting

I have the following code working as expected outside UserFrosting:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World.<br>";

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Common\Aws;

$aws = Aws::factory('../aws/aws-config.json');
$client = $aws->get('S3');

$bucket = 'my-public-public';

$iterator = $client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket
));

foreach ($iterator as $object) {
    echo $object['Key'] . "<br>";
}
```

On my UserFrosting instance I managed to successfully load **aws-sdk-php** with Composer:

```
  - Installing aws/aws-sdk-php (3.19.24)
    Downloading: 100%
```

*use Aws\Common\Aws;* is placed in **initialize.php**, below reference to Slim:

```
use \Slim\Extras\Middleware\CsrfGuard;
use Aws\Common\Aws;
```

The rest of the code is in the controller:

```
    public function readS3(){
        $aws = Aws::factory('../aws/aws-config.json');
        $client = $aws->get('S3');
        ...
    }
```

I am still getting the following error:

> Class 'UserFrosting\Aws' not found.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, it is looking in the `UserFrosting\` namespace for the `Aws` class, but it clearly does not live in there!

You need the `use Aws\Common\Aws;` at the top of **every** file where you want to reference the class `Aws`.  Alternatively, you can simply reference the class using its fully qualified name:

`$aws = \Aws\Common\Aws::factory('../aws/aws-config.json');`

I would suggest taking an hour or so to learn more about [PHP Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).  They are an extremely important concept in modern PHP, and are closely related to Composer, autoloading, and the [PSR-4 standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

Comment: To add to this, there is no way to address the OP's specific error without seeing more code context to understand where/how the `UserFrosting` namespace is invoked, but this answer should get the OP pointing in the right direction.

Comment: @MikeBrant Most [controller files](https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/blob/master/userfrosting/controllers/AccountController.php) in this version of UserFrosting start with `namespace UserFrosting;` at the top.  So if OP isn't familiar with namespaces, they probably don't realize that PHP will consider this the namespace for ALL references to classes unless explicitly declared otherwise.